# A technology to push data from a server to a desktop Java application

Tags: push, comet, server-push

I have a Java desktop application, which needs to be updated with data from a web server continuously.

Since the desktop application could be used in a mobile environment (e.g. on a laptop with a 3G modem), there is no way to connect with it through the client's IP address.

What is the 'best practice' on pushing data to a [mobile] client from a server?

I have heard that Comet is a new emerging technology, does something similar exist for desktop (non-browser) applications?

By the way, what is the most mature technology for doing that in a web browser client? Comet, HTML5 or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comet really has nothing to do with the web aside from it's use of HTTP. The client (web page or desktop application) simply opens an HTTP connection, and it's up to the server to keep it open until it has something to tell the client. If/When the http connection times out on either end, the client simply makes another HTTP call to the same endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, Joel. Can a connection be open 24/7?

Comment: I believe most libraries on the server and client will time out eventually. I suppose there's nothing in the HTTP spec that mandates a timeout, just that there can be timeouts. But that shouldn't really concern you. If you're going to use something like "comet", then a timeout is a natural part of the protocol. Once it times out, simply open another connection.